How can we change puppet-lint settings in the VSCode extension?
I'm starting to do Puppet development for our Windows environment in an environment that uses slightly different formatting standards for our puppet code than what the VSCode extension/linter flags as problems.  One example of a problem flagged by the extension is indentation.
indent should be 2 chars and is 4 Puppet(strict_indent)
Is there a way to set our own formatting standards so that this doesn't show as a problem?  We also use multiple lines between classes.  In both cases, this is for code readability that is preferred over the default formatting that the extension suggests.
I've reviewed documentation and the only thing I've been able to find is how to change indenting specifically for VSCode itself but that doesn't change the setting for the linter itself which still flags our indentation standard as a problem.

Does this help: https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-lint-strict_indent-check?tab=readme-ov-file#alternate-indentation
